# Send data from computer to phone through bluetooth - Bluetooth SeeedStudio Shield V2.1

Tags: bluetooth, shields

So I bought a Bluetooth Shield from SeeedStudio lately (V2 model) and goofed around with it a little bit. I'm using my HTC One M8 to communicate with it just to send some dummy words. Whenever I send something from my phone to the Android, it works great and I'm pleased to see it's fast too.

The code is fairly simple. I just send data from my phone, gets received to my arduino, prints it on the Arduino IDE terminal. Same thing for communication in the other way. Write something in the terminal, send it to the arduino and then, the phone. The last on doesn't work and I've tried a couple of things in the past 36 hours. Now, I'm just banging my head against the wall (literally). Here's my code (I'm sure you've seen it a couple of times before):

```c
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>   //Software Serial Port
#define RxD 6
#define TxD 7

#define DEBUG_ENABLED  1

SoftwareSerial blueToothSerial(RxD,TxD);

void setup() 
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(RxD, INPUT);
  pinMode(TxD, OUTPUT);
  setupBlueToothConnection();

} 

void loop() 
{ 
  char recvChar;
  while(1){
    if(blueToothSerial.available()){//check if there's any data sent from the remote bluetooth shield
      recvChar = blueToothSerial.read();
      Serial.print(recvChar);
    }
    if(Serial.available()){//check if there's any data sent from the local serial terminal, you can add the other applications here
      recvChar  = Serial.read();
      blueToothSerial.print(recvChar);
    }
  }
} 

void setupBlueToothConnection()
{
  blueToothSerial.begin(9600); //Set BluetoothBee BaudRate to default baud rate 38400
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STWMOD=0\r\n"); //set the bluetooth work in slave mode
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STNA=SeeedBTSlave\r\n"); //set the bluetooth name as "SeeedBTSlave"
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STOAUT=1\r\n"); // Permit Paired device to connect me
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STAUTO=0\r\n"); // Auto-connection should be forbidden here
  delay(2000); // This delay is required.
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+INQ=1\r\n"); //make the slave bluetooth inquirable 
  Serial.println("The slave bluetooth is inquirable!");
  delay(2000); // This delay is required.
  blueToothSerial.flush();
}
```

On my phone, I use a simple Bluetooth SSP to pair and communicate. Btw, something odd: I can't change the name of the bluetooth device. When I try to connect it, it shows the same name in the SSP.

Note: When I upload my code, I make sure I reset the arduino everytime. Oh and I changed the jumpers on my board to make sure it was set on the right one.

Note 2: I tried to see if the pins on the Shield (for RdX and TdX) were not starting with 0 by moving the jumpers.

Still, it's pretty odd.

Thanks in advance for any help and don't hesitate to ask me question! It's my first time here!